# Get IPv4 out of a Ruby string that contains both IPv4 and IPv6?

Tags: ruby, string, ip, ip-address

I have a string from the `X-Forwarded-For` header that contains both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.

I need to pull just the IPv4 address from the string.

It's comma-separated, but the order of them changes so I can't just split and pull the second item.

Example: `header = 2600:1740:8540:cff9:1c50:617:c9c5:63f7, 165.154.107.112`

I ultimately just want `165.154.107.112`.

I'm using Ruby 2.5.1 *(and this happens to be inside a Rails 5.2.0 app, for what it's worth)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your header is always as you've posted:

```
require 'ipaddr'

header = "165.154.107.112, 2600:1740:8540:cff9:1c50:617:c9c5:63f7"

ip = header.split(', ').select {|ip| ip if IPAddr.new(ip).ipv4? }.pop

# => "165.154.107.112"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
header = "2600:1740:8540:cff9:1c50:617:c9c5:63f7, 165.154.107.112, 166.155.108.113"

header.split(/\s?,\s?/).find { |s| IPAddr.new(s).ipv4? }
  #=> "165.154.107.112"
```

or

```
header.split(/,\s+/).select { |s| IPAddr.new(s).ipv4? }
  #=> ["165.154.107.112", "166.155.108.113"]
```

See [IPAddr::new](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html#method-c-new) and [IPAddr#ipv4?](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html#method-i-ipv4-3F).

If `"header = "` is part of the string `str`, replace `header.split` with `str[/\d.+/].split`.

If the string may contain text that is not a valid IP address, you could write the following.

```
header.split(/\s?,\s?/).find { |s| (IPAddr.new(s) rescue nil)&.ipv4? }
```

`IPAddr.new('cat')`, for example, raises the exception `IPAddr::InvalidAddressError (invalid address)`. `&` is Ruby's [safe navigation operator](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/), which made it's debut in v2.3.

Comment: I forgot to include `require 'ipaddr'`, but the code ran fine without it (using Ruby v2.5.1). I then noticed that `ipaddr` is a ["default gem"](https://stdgems.org/2.5.1/) in Ruby v2.5.1, but not in v2.4. Does that mean `require 'ipaddr'` is not needed in v2.5.1+?